# Number of binary sequences in which the number of $(1, 1)$ and $(0, 0)$ is prespecified

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Consider a binary sequence $\mathbf{a}_n$ consisting of 1s and 0s.
Let us denote by $f(\mathbf{a}_n)$ the number of $(1, 1)$ and $(0, 0)$ in $\mathbf{a}_n$; I am not sure whether there is a formal name for $f(\mathbf{a}_n)$.
Is there a closed expression for the number of $\mathbf{a}_n$'s such that $f(\mathbf{a}_n) = i$  for
$i = 0, 1, \dotsc, n - 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the related binary sequence $\widetilde{a_n}$ of length $n-1$ defined by $\widetilde{a_n}(k) := (a_n(k+1)-a_n(k))\text{ mod }2$ for $k = 0\ldots n-2$; the number of 0's in $\widetilde{a_n}$ is exactly the number of $(0,0)'s$ and $(1,1)'s$ in $a_n$. Now, the number of binary sequences of length $(n-1)$ which have exactly $i$ 0's is just $\binom{n-1}{i}$, and each $\widetilde{a_n}$ arises from two distinct $a_n$'s (one with $a_n(0) = 0$ and one with $a_n(0) = 1$), so it follows that $\left|\{a_n|f(a_n) = i\}\right| = 2\binom{n-1}{i}$.